# Socket.io 2.0.3 Websockets are now tracked by chrome console or I did a mistake?

Tags: javascript, node.js, nginx, socket.io

I'm using Node.js 6.9.0, Nginx and Socket.io 2.0.3. I'm following this [tutorial](https://socket.io/get-started/chat/) but when I open the chrome console and when I send a message in the chat box I can see all requests.

```
Request : http:/example.com/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=LpK5axT&sid=FURqXUKj-bE3OuZAAG

Response : 21:42["myevent","Hello world"]
```

I remember with socket.io < 2.0 I couldn't see the chat message event in the chrome console. And when I go to the [chat demo](https://socket.io/demos/chat/) I can't see the traffic too. That is why I think I made a mistake (But the demo use socket.io 1.7).

Here is my code :

**Client side :**

```
<body>
    <ul id="messages"></ul>
    <form action="">
        <input id="m" autocomplete="off" /><button>Send</button>
    </form>
    <script>
    $(function () {
        var socket = io();
        $('form').submit(function(){
            socket.emit('myevent', $('#m').val());
            $('#m').val('');
            return false;
        });
        socket.on('myevent', function(msg){
            $('#messages').append($('<li>').text(msg));
            window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);
        });
    });
    </script>
    <!-- <div id="map-canvas"></div> -->
</body>
```

**Server side**

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var http = require('http').Server(app);
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var path = require('path');
var io = require('socket.io')(http);

// set the view engine to ejs
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '/public')));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

io.on('connection', function(socket) {
    socket.on('myevent', function(data) {
        data.socketId = socket.id;
        io.emit('myevent', data);
    });
});

// Listen on port 3002
http.listen(3002, function() {
    console.log('Server running at *:3002');
});
```

What do you think ?

Comment: Socket.io uses normal AJAX and eventually goes over to websockets. That might be the reason

Comment: But why we can't see the request in the version 1.x ?